# PHP project: Includes and project layout

Tags: php, project

I have dabbled in php and read a lot both across Stack Overflow and php.net documentation but I fear I have the wrong idea on what goes where my understanding is as follows.

1. included files a best to be held in the includes folder, these things are like functions specific to files ie: users.php would hold the functions for user related items in this folder
2. project root would hold a config.php for items like db root and other set specific items
3. includes drill down like so but only from project root

`include('includes/user.php');`

this is where my questions are.

1. do I have a general idea or is their an easier way to layout a complex project
2. is a function like

   `function includes($path, $location){
   return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. "/" .$path. "/" .$location;
   }`

and usage like

`require(includes('includes', 'functions.php'));`

be a smart way to accomplish includes accorss the project

1. how do major projects like joomla, phpbb & vbulletin accomplish includes I have looked it over but I am confused totally on how they accomplish this.
2. anything else that needs to be taken into consideration with project layout and including. im looking at separating group of functions together in their own files

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a layout for a complex project that both your **and** other developers will understand, you should look into using an [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) framework.

PHP frameworks include:

- [Symfony](http://symfony.com/)
- [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/)
- [Laravel](http://laravel.com/)
- [Code Igniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)
- [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/)

Comment: thanks I suspected that going back to codeigniter for the project was my best option

Answer (score 0):

Typically, for huge projects, my project layout is as follows:

include folder contains
- config.php (DB Connection)
- init.php

controller folder contains all controllers to handle $_POST and data validation

view folder contains all web pages. these are the ones whose URLs the visitors will remember

utility folder contains all SQL scripts (INSERT/CREATE/DELETE)

Of course, you have your js, css folders

So intuitively, a **view** will include its own **controller**.
A **controller** will include the **init.php** and
the **init.php** includes the **config.php** to establish DB connection and all utilities so you can easily call methods for CRUD purposes...

Other people have their styles, but this is mine.

Comment: so are we talking about going to a MVC kind of style, this gives me the impression it would be `example.com/views/login.php`

Comment: yeah, something like this. then you can have the `login.php` include `login.ctrl.php` from the controller folder. There are,of course frameworks out there that can be considered too.